# Converting Units in formula

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, units

I have the following formula

```
\[HBar] = hbar = (6.6260693*joule*sec)/(10^34*(2*Pi)); 

chp[Te_, ne_, 
  M_] := (1.3806505*(joule/kelvin)*Te*kelvin*
    Log[1 - Exp[-((2*Pi*hbar^2*
            ne*(10^11/(cm*cm)))/((4*M*9.1093826*kg*kelvin*
              Te*1.3806505*(joule/kelvin))/(10^31*10^23)))]])/10^23

chp[50, 1, 0.5]

(* 6.90325*10^-22 joule Log[
  1 - E^(-((5.55596*10^-6 joule sec^2)/(cm^2 kg)))] *)
```

My question is what is the best way to have an output that is in eV. Please note that the argument of the Exp is unitless...even though it is expressed in terms of cm, kg etc. So the output should only be in terms of eV.

Comment: Have you looked into `Quantity` and `UnitConvert`?

Comment: Yes.....just how do you use them for this particular relation.....in a neat way. I can do it ...a bit messily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `Quantity` and `UnitConvert`, and defining your units beforehand.

```
kelvin = Quantity[1, "Kelvins"];
joule = Quantity[1, "Joules"];
\[HBar] = hbar = Quantity[1, "ReducedPlanckConstant"];
cm = Quantity[1, "Centimeters"];
kg = Quantity[1, "Kilograms"];
chp[Te_, ne_, 
  M_] := (1.3806505*(joule/kelvin)*Te*kelvin*
    Log[1 - Exp[
       UnitConvert[-((2*Pi*hbar^2*
             ne*(10^11/(cm*cm)))/((4*M*9.1093826*kg*kelvin*
               Te*1.3806505*(joule/kelvin))/(10^31*10^23)))]]])/10^23

UnitConvert[chp[50, 1, 0.5], "Electronvolts"]
```

results in

```
Quantity[-0.0125725, "Electronvolts"]
```

Comment: Thks, I have modified my code to include "DimensionlessUnit"...this was what I was looking for...useful in calculations involving several related formulas.

Comment: @Michael Witt I had to wrap the argument of the exponent in the `chp` function with `UnitConvert[-((2*Pi*hbar^2...]` in order to get it to work.

Comment: @JackLaVigne Yeah, for some reason it ran when I tested it initially, but didn't run now. I've updated my solution to include the `UnitConvert` in the argument of the exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that "DimensionlessUnit" would help greatly, so the code is

```
\[HBar] = hbar = (6.6260693*10^-34)/(2 \[Pi]); (* Joule*Second*)



chp1[Te_] := 
 UnitConvert[Quantity[1.3806505*10^-23 Te, "Joule"], 
  Quantity["Electronvolts"]]

chp2[Te_, ne_, M_] := 
 chp1[Te]*Log[1 - Exp[-UnitConvert[ Quantity[(2 Pi hbar^2  ne 10^11)/
 (4 M 9.1093826*(10^-31) Te 1.3806505*(10^-23) ), "Joules"*"Seconds"^2
  /("Centimeters"^2*"Kilograms")], Quantity["DimensionlessUnit"]]]]


chp2[50, 1, 0.5]
 (* - 0.0125725 eV *)
```